# IE prompt about unsaved form data

Tags: css, forms, internet-explorer, prompt

I'm having an unexpected "annoying" popup in IE7 (and possibly other versions). As expected IE prompts you about unsaved form data when closing the window which is fine. But I have a `form` inside a `div` and now when I toggle the `display` CSS style between `none` and `block`, IE thinks I'm closing the form with unsaved data and shows the warning about closing an unsaved form! I don't want my users to be annoyed when simply hiding a form in my IE-based web app.

Anyone know how to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your doc type is transitional rather than strict

Comment: Unfortunately didn't get rid of the prompt. Silly IE!

Answer (score 0):

The prompt isn't IE's-- **your HTML** has an onbeforeunload handler which triggers the warning.

Comment: It does? Or should I have one?

Comment: IE itself doesn't show a prompt when you close it unless your HTML contains an OnBeforeUnload handler.